# vlookup directory pointing to a specific directory

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am having this problem when running my vba script. It is supposed to open up 4 excel files and one template with a macro. Then it activate the macro and populate each table with vlookup to the specific excel file. The 2 sheets have 3 columns, 2 columns are looking for 1 excel file and the 3rd column looks for the 2nd excel file. But when i run the script, the first 2 columns are #NA whereas the 3rd column has the file directory to the excel file. When i do it manually(Manually open all 4 excel files and click on a button to run the macro), it successfully populate all 3 columns for both sheets. What could be the problem? I searched around and vlookup searches for excel files that are opened, thats why i open the 4 excel files before running the macro to populate the tables.
This is my VBA Script:

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp, xlBook, shell
Dim folderPath


' Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")   
' shell.Run "C:\Users\NLTAdmin\Desktop\Extraction_Automation\TABLE_COUNT_SCRIPT\All_in_one.bat", 1, True


folderPath = "C:\Users\NLTAdmin\Desktop\Extraction_Automation\TABLE_COUNT_SCRIPT\"

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

xlApp.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "Assetco\Assetco.csv")
xlApp.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "BIOS\BIOS.csv")
' xlApp.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "FDS\FDS.csv")
' xlApp.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "FTTH\FTTH.csv")
' xlApp.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "FTTH_Filter\ftth_union_filter_queries.csv")
' xlApp.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "Gtech_Filter\Gtech_filter_queries.csv")
' xlApp.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "Gtechv1\Gtech.csv")
' xlApp.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "MARS\MARS.csv")
' xlApp.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "MARS_Filter\mars_filter_queries.csv")
' xlApp.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "WOMS\WOMS.csv")
' xlApp.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "Workflow\WORKFLOW.csv")
' xlApp.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "Workflow_Filter\workflow_filter_queries.csv")

folderPath = "C:\Users\NLTAdmin\Desktop\Extraction_Automation\Union_queries\"

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

xlApp.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "ASSETCO_union.csv")
xlApp.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "BIOS_union.csv")
' xlApp.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "FDS_union.csv")
' xlApp.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "FTTH_union.csv")
' xlApp.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "GTECH_union.csv")
' xlApp.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "MARS_union.csv")
' xlApp.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "WOMS_union.csv")
' xlApp.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "WORKFLOW_union.csv")

set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\NLTAdmin\Desktop\Extraction_Automation\extraction_report_template.xlsm",0,True)
xlApp.Run "Macro1"

xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True
xlApp.Quit

Set xlApp = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

The first Workbooks.open is suppose to open the excel files to populate the first 2 columns, whereas the 2nd Workbooks.Open is to populate the 3rd column. Only the 3rd column gets populated.
3rd column has the file directory and is populated:
[image: 3rd column has the file directory]
1st and 2nd column unable to be found
[image: 1st column]

Comment: Maybe i can use INDIRECT() since the excel files are all opened? Can someone guide me on how to use this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Excel in VBScript

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp, xlBook, shell
Dim folderPath

'  Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'  shell.Run "C:\Users\NLTAdmin\Desktop\Extraction_Automation\ _
'      & "TABLE_COUNT_SCRIPT\All_in_one.bat", 1, True

  folderPath = "C:\Users\NLTAdmin\Desktop\Extraction_Automation\" _
      & "TABLE_COUNT_SCRIPT\"

  ' To avoid multiple instances of Excel, when it is running,
  ' the GetObject Method has to be used, but when Excel is not running
  ' the CreateObject Method has to be used to open it.
  On Error Resume Next
  ' When Excel is running:
  Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")      ' Excel is running
  If Err Then
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")   ' Excel not running.
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0

  With xlApp
    .Visible = True
    .DisplayAlerts = False

    .Workbooks.Open (folderPath & "Assetco\Assetco.csv")
    .Workbooks.Open (folderPath & "BIOS\BIOS.csv")
' .Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "FDS\FDS.csv")
' .Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "FTTH\FTTH.csv")
' .Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "FTTH_Filter\ftth_union_filter_queries.csv")
' .Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "Gtech_Filter\Gtech_filter_queries.csv")
' .Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "Gtechv1\Gtech.csv")
' .Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "MARS\MARS.csv")
' .Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "MARS_Filter\mars_filter_queries.csv")
' .Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "WOMS\WOMS.csv")
' .Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "Workflow\WORKFLOW.csv")
' .Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "Workflow_Filter\workflow_filter_queries.csv")

    folderPath = "C:\Users\NLTAdmin\Desktop\Extraction_Automation\" _
        & "Union_queries\"

    .Workbooks.Open (folderPath & "ASSETCO_union.csv")
    .Workbooks.Open (folderPath & "BIOS_union.csv")
' .Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "FDS_union.csv")
' .Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "FTTH_union.csv")
' .Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "GTECH_union.csv")
' .Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "MARS_union.csv")
' .Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "WOMS_union.csv")
' .Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "WORKFLOW_union.csv")

    Set xlBook = .Workbooks.Open(folderPath _
        & "extraction_report_template.xlsm", 0, True)
    .Run "Macro1"

    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .Quit

  End With

  Set xlApp = Nothing

  WScript.Quit
```

Answer (score 1):

You creating multiple instances of Excel.  Eliminate all but the first `CreateObject("Excel.Application")`'

> ```
>  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
> ```